# Javascript ImagePreview

Tags: javascript, html, image

I need a preview of an image after it got upload via `<input type="file onchange="readURL(this);">`.

I have found a solution on the internet, but that doesn't work for me:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
 }
```

"#blah" is the ID of the image(it is shown with a placeholder at first).
 The Error I get when opening the Console, after I uploaded an image : **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at FileReader.reader.onload ((index):156)**

But it works here : https://codepen.io/mobifreaks/pen/LIbca

Please give me a short explanation why this doesn't work for me and the solution to it.

```js
  function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
              $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
   }
```

```css
#preview {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" style="margin-left:1px" onchange="readURL(this);"/><br>
<img id="preview" src="" alt=""/>
```

Comment: You are just missing     `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">` reference into your file and it should work. This can be achieved without jquery too

Comment: Either jQuery is missing or you are not aware that `$` is the alias for the jQuery and you forgot to add it in the page. Instead just translate it in javascript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You must import the jquery.min.js